# function to append in different type of calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to create a function that append the parameter values. The important thing is that it should accept the bellow given function calls

```
concat('hello', 'world');
concat('hello')('world');
```

both of these should return "helloworld". How is that possible?

Comment: What about just .join()?

Comment: Do you know how `concat('hello')('world');` will behave?

Comment: what should return if `concat('hello')('world')('!!!');` or `concat('hello','wonder')('world')('!!!');`

Comment: my code is given bellow 
    function concat(a,b) {
  alert(a+b);  
 }
 a = 'hello';
 b = 'ddfdf';
 //concat(a,b);
 concat(a)(b);

Comment: it returns "hellowundefined"

Comment: If this two example is all you need, see my answer. If you need more functionally see `@Chris Hayes` answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for the specifications in the question, plus a little extra:

```
function concat(/* varargs */) {
    // Called with multiple arguments: concatenate them immediately
    var originalArgs = [].slice.call(arguments);
    if (originalArgs.length > 1) {
        return originalArgs.join("");
    }

    // Called with zero or one arg: return a function that will perform the concatenation later
    return function(/* varargs */) {
        var newArgs = [].slice.call(arguments);
        var combinedArgs = originalArgs.concat(newArgs);
        return concat.apply(null, combinedArgs);
    }
}

concat('a', 'b'); // 'ab'
concat('a')('b'); // 'ab'
concat('a', 'b', 'c'); // 'abc'
concat('a')('b', 'c'); // 'abc'
```

That said, it won't extend past two calls (and I don't think it's possible to create a function which would) and it reeks of overengineering. I'd seriously reconsider whether you need this function.

Comment: +1 i was amazed seeing the implementation of **concat('a')('b')** hats off.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function concat(a,b){
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
        return function(c){return a+c;};
    } else if (arguments.length == 2) {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `+` operator to concatenate strings. Really no need for any special functions unless there's a specific use.

For example:

```
var string = 'hello, ' + 'world' + '!!!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way

```
function concat(){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).reduce(function(a,b){return a.concat(b)},[]),
        internal = concat.bind(this,args);

    internal.toString = function(){return args.join('');}
    return internal
}
```

for using

```
console.log(concat('hello', 'world')) //helloworld
console.log(concat('hello')('world')) // helloworld
console.log(concat('hello')('world','!!!')) //helloworld!!!
console.log(concat('hello')('world')('!!!')) //helloworld!!!
```